# Passing data from UItableviewController to UItableViewcell in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I need to pass an string value from UItable View Controller to Uitable view cell

Here is the code which i used
In my Table view controller

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface DetViewController : UITableViewController
{
NSString *urlstring;

CustomCell *cust;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *urlstring;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *mutarray;

@property(nonatomic,retain)CustomCell *cust;
@end
```

and im TableViewController.m have

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];  
 url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];

urldata=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
mutarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

self.mutarray=[urldata JSONValue];



 NSDictionary *dict=[mutarray objectAtIndex:0];

self.title=[dict valueForKey:@"category"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomCell *cell =(CustomCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}

cell.custurlstring=urlstring;
NSLog(@"%@", cell.custurlstring);
return cell;
}
```

In my Custom Tableviewcell.h have

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell{
NSString *custurlstring;


}
@end
```

My custom Tableviewcell.m have

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {

  NSLog(@"%@",custurlstring);
}
return self;
}
```

Now i got the string content in tableviewcontroller by using NSLog..but if i tried to print the value in TableViewCell i cant get those values...
Guidance Please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of customizing a cell for displaying a image and labels on it,
Just add them in normal cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {        
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:<style enum value> reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier string:urlstring]
    //cell.mystring = self.mystring;
}

// customize your image and your labels here with rects here


UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:image];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(your rect here)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup your cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and then set the string on the cell inside this method. This method is already provided to you when you create a `UITableViewController`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.custurlstring = urlstring;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Because you're logging it during the `init`. As you can see from the method, the string *isn't* being set until after the cell has been initialized. Add `NSLog(@"%@", cell.custurlstring);` just below `cell.custurlstring = urlstring;`

Comment: So if i try to implement in custom TableViewcell do i have to initialise as cell.custurlstring or as custurlstring...?

Comment: I got it by using your command by NSLog(@"%@", cell.custurlstring); in table view controller..but if i tried to print that in custom tableviewcell its not getting..i have declared aas NSLog(@"%@",custurlstring);

Comment: It is coming up null in your `UITableViewCell` because you are trying to log it during the `init`.  It does not exist at the point of initialization.  It is being set AFTER the cell is initialized.

Comment: Log it in your `drawRect:` method and it'll show up. Perhaps you should consider just starting with the default cells and get familiar with `UITableView` and then move onto implementing custom cells?

Answer (score 1):

You should do it in delegate method - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

You can write something like that:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {        
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:<style enum value> reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier string:urlstring]
    //cell.mystring = self.mystring;
}

return cell;
}
```

Added:
You can write custom constructor and initialize the cell using it. This way NSLog will print the string as expected:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier string:(NSString *)string
{
self = [self initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {

 self.custurl=[NSURL URLWithString:string];
  NSLog(@"%@",custurl);
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: You print custurl in the init function, but value added later.

Comment: even if i tried to print in init function it returns null...if i tried to print that cust url value in tableviewcontroller it says null..that means the values are not assigned custurl right?..

Comment: try to add property: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *custurlstring; in your CustomCell declaration. And check that initial table view string has value...

Comment: I got it by using command by NSLog(@"%@", cell.custurlstring); in table view controller..but if i tried to print that in custom tableviewcell its not getting..i have declared aas NSLog(@"%@",custurlstring);